# Method of ascent to prove that $x^2 − 3y^2 = 1$ has infinitely many solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Use the method of ascent to prove there are infinitely many solutions to the Diophantine
equation: $$x^2 − 3y^2 = 1$$
We can do this by showing how, given one solution $(u, v)$, we can compute another solution
$(w, z)$ that is larger is some suitable sense. Then my proof will involve finding a pair of
formulas, something like: $w = x + y$ and $z = x − y$.
However I tried these formulas and they don't work. So I asked my teacher and she said that there is a pair of second degree formulas which do work; one of them has a cross term and one of them involves the number 3.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you help me with this?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648781/proof-that-the-equation-x2-3y2-1-has-infinite-solutions-for-x-and-y/648812#648812

Comment: @G.H.Faust Does that use the method of ascent though?

Comment: If you read the last couple of lines of my answer, it should become clear that it does.

Comment: @G.H.Faust So this question and that question are completely the same?

Comment: There's always a bit of a grey area re what is a duplicate and what is not, but I would say they are the same, yes.

Comment: With basic algebraic number theory concepts in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ this problem is a breeze. Without those concepts, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the norm over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$,
$$ N(a+b\sqrt{3}) = (a+b\sqrt{3})(a-b\sqrt{3}) = a^2-3b^2. $$
The norm is multiplicative, hence if we found a unit (i.e. an element with unit norm) in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, from $N(z^n)=N(z)^n=1$ we get an infinite number of solutions for $a^2-3b^2 = 1$. For instance, the trivial solution $a=2,b=1$ gives that $(a,b)=(7,4)$ is also a solution, since:

$$ (2+\sqrt{3})^2 = 7+4\sqrt{3}. $$
As a consequence, if we consider the two sequences defined by:
$$ a_1=2,\qquad a_2=7,\qquad a_{n+2}=4 a_{n+1}-a_{n}, $$
$$ b_1=1,\qquad b_2=4, \qquad b_{n+2}=4b_{n+1}-b_n, $$
we have that for every $n\geq 1$
$$ a_n^2-3b_n^2 = 1 $$
holds.